# how to use content type with image

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a radiobuttonlist which display a list of images based on the extension, not the actual image but the path. How do I use a Content type to display the selected images?

Comment: I do not understand this question. The first paragraph seems like a copy and paste from somewhere. And I do not understand how you would use a Content Type to display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using Webforms. In that case, your best bet is to create an HttpHandler (a file ending in .ashx). It is lighter weight than a full asp.net page. Then put logic in the ProcessRequest method.

```
    public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
    {
        var path = context.Request.QueryString["path"];
        // read image bytes
        byte[] image = ReadImage(path);

        // using "image/jpeg" as an example. Use actual type for file extension
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(resizedStream.GetBuffer());
    }
```

Then, on your aspx page, you can create an image control and set the url to be the url of the handler you just created. You can pass whatever parameters in the querystring you need to get the correct image.